# Specify integral template argument of constructor template inside a class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor

I am creating a `std::tuple` equivalent for a `union` (instead of a `struct`). To do so, I also added a constructor template, where the first template argument is `size_t idx`, to initize the idx<sup>th</sup> element of the `union`. Moreover, there is another `variadic template` to specify what the argments of the actual type constructor are.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to specify the `idx` template argument when calling the constructor, and it is also not implied (as it is not part of the argument list). Is there any way around this? How can I specify a `size_t` contructor template argument?

Example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T d_val;
    size_t d_other_val;
    template<size_t idx>
    Foo(T val)
    {
        d_val = val;
        d_other_val = idx;
    }
};


int main() {
    Foo<double> f = Foo<4>(2.6);

    std::cout << f.d_val << " " << f.d_other_val << '\n';
}
```

Source: http://ideone.com/UeBvF5

Of course, the 4 is matched on the class template, and not the constructor template. Is this fixable? Note that idx should be a compile time thing, and not a normal constructor argument. Although in this example, that would be the trivial solution.

PS: the problem of course is, that in general constructor templates are implied by the arguments with which the constructor is called. Implicit specification is to the best of my knowledge not possible for the idx template argument.

Comment: template argument should be deduced for constructor.

Comment: "Although in this example, that would be the trivial solution." - so, can you show us a better example? if the parameter cannot be deduced, I see no point of using a template.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think that requires quite some code, at least, I cannot think of a simple example. However, think about implementing a union as a  class template, with the union members specified using a variadic template argument. Then, the size_t template argument of the constructor template is used to specify which of these union members should be initialized. This can be done runtime, but then the constructor would need to do runtime recursion as well, which in theory can be done compiletime.

Comment: @Herbert: hmm.. use a factory?

Comment: Yes, I am using a factory, more or less now, but a constructor would have been simpler  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[temp.arg.explicit]/7` reads:

> [ *Note:* Because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name, and because conversion
>   member function templates and constructor member function templates are called without using a
>   function name, there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these function templates.
>   *—end note* ]

So you have to either pass `size_t idx` as a regular parameter, or add it as `struct Foo`'s template parameter.

Comment: To be clear: This is not a solution, just an explanation of why there is no solution. I find it a bit unfortunate, since this is a syntax-only reason, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Herbert Yes, it can be thought of as a syntax-only reason: you can't specify template arguments for function without a name.